# cllick event of dynamically created Checkbox in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkboxlist from which I want to get check event.

> the checkboxes are created dynamically.

I am not able to fire the event

what I tried so far is

```
$(".XAxisrowCheckbox").click(function () {

            //Do stuff

    });
```

I also tried with this

```
    $("input.XAxisrowCheckbox").click(function () {

            //Do stuff

    });
```

but no luck for me. Tag goes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="XAxisrowCheckbox">
```

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jQuery.on` accepts selector as an argument (http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.XAxisrowCheckbox', function () {
    //do stuff
});
```